# Email.ID in Exact Target SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud, .net

This is regarding Exact Target API terminology. I am currently trying to test TriggeredSend in the APIStarterkit project in .NET. I am currently learning and testing samples.

Can anybody advise what is email ID (em.ID) here in below code ? I didn't understand what  this is and why we require this ? Where do we find this value ?

```
 Email em = new Email();
 em.ID = XXXXXXXX;//required //Available in the ET UI [Content > My Emails > Properties]
 em.IDSpecified = true;//required
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link on triggered sending](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/) should help you understand the process of triggered sending from ExactTarget's perspective.

The email ID is required to select the correct email to send the subscriber. The code you referenced shows a comment where you can find the ID in the UI.  You can also return all email objects with the API.